# Is there a better way to identify time interval boundaries of a series pattern?

Tags: sql, sql-server, analysis, aggregation

I have a table of payments, with positive and negative values (i.e., captures and credits).  I need to identify the points where we've received a net positive amount, since the last net positive amount.  For example, if the customer makes these payments and receives these credits:

```
01/01  $100 <-
02/01 -$100
03/01 -$100
04/01  $100
05/01  $100
06/01  $100 <-
```

...then the points would be 01/01 and 06/01: as of 02/01 through 04/01, they have a negative balance, and as of 05/01 they have a zero balance.

My current approach starts by building a list of end dates from all dates with a capture, then calculates a start date for each of these, and finally calculates the net captures for these periods:

```
Start      End        NetCaptures
1900/01/01 2011/01/01  $100
2011/01/02 2011/04/01 -$100
2011/04/02 2011/05/01  $100
2011/05/02 2011/06/01  $100
```

I then discard records with a NetCaptures of $0 or less, recalculate start dates, recalculate net captures, and repeat until there are no records to delete, leaving this.

```
Start      End        NetCaptures
1900/01/01 2011/01/01  $100
2011/01/02 2011/06/01  $100
```

Is there a better way to do this?  Some clever use of analysis expressions?  This is getting close to RBAR.  In practice, it runs acceptably quickly (ten minutes for 500K records, versus 1.5 before I started accounting for credits in this way).

* RESULT ***

While Microsoft does support a graceful rolling total function, using that thought I ended up with code like this: calculate all captures, calculate the running total up to each one, and discard those where there is an earlier record that has an equal or greater running total.

```
CREATE TABLE #Sequences
    (
    OrderID INT NOT NULL,
    Sequence    INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID, Sequence),
    StartDate   DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-01-01',
    EndDate DATE NOT NULL,
    CapturesThisPeriod  DECIMAL(18, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    )
INSERT INTO #Sequences (OrderID, Sequence, EndDate)
    SELECT OrderID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY DateReceived), DateReceived
    FROM Receipts
    WHERE Amount > 0.00

/* Calculate the start date for each period */
UPDATE S
SET StartDate = DATEADD(D, 1, Prev.EndDate)
FROM
    #Sequences AS S
    INNER JOIN #Sequences AS Prev ON S.OrderID = Prev.OrderID AND Prev.Sequence = S.Sequence - 1

/* Calculate the cumulative total for each period */
UPDATE M
SET CumulativeReceipts = R.Receipts
FROM
    #Sequences AS M
    INNER JOIN      
        (
        SELECT
            M.OrderID, M.Sequence, SUM(R.Amount) AS Receipts
        FROM
            #Sequences AS M
            INNER JOIN Receipts AS R ON M.OrderID = R.OrderID AND R.DateReceived <= M.EndDate
        GROUP BY
            M.OrderID, M.Sequence
        ) AS R ON M.OrderID = R.OrderID AND M.Sequence = R.Sequence

/* Delete sequences with do not represent net positive receipts */
DELETE FROM M
FROM #Sequences AS M
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #Sequences AS Prev WHERE M.OrderID = Prev.OrderID AND Prev.Sequence < M.Sequence AND Prev.CumulativeReceipts >= M.CumulativeReceipts)

/* Recalculate sequence numbers and dates */
UPDATE S SET Sequence = NewSequence FROM (SELECT Sequence, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY Sequence) AS NewSequence FROM #Sequences) AS S
UPDATE S
SET StartDate = DATEADD(D, 1, Prev.EndDate)
FROM
    #Sequences AS S
    INNER JOIN #Sequences AS Prev ON S.OrderID = Prev.OrderID AND Prev.Sequence = S.Sequence - 1
    END

/* Calculate net captures per period, and continue with analysis */
```

Comment: Search around for "running sum"; for example, http://explainextended.com/2010/01/22/sql-server-running-totals/

Comment: Are you saying you want the local peaks of a curve? ie. whenever the curve rises above the previous maximum? Or are you interested in when the curve rises above zero?

Comment: @Andomar, I believe that's exactly what I need!  If you'd like to add that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.  I knew that had to be a simpler way.  I'll post my code when it's implemented.  @Lasse, based on a running total, I'm looking for all points above zero.  I was stuck on implementing per-unit values, I did not think to start with the cumulative total and backtrack from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search around for "running sum"; for example, http://explainextended.com/2010/01/22/sql-server-running-totals

Comment: This would be so easy if Microsoft implemented `SUM() OVER (ORDER BY)`.